# Cannot create SQLAlchemy engine, getting error "loaded 'mysqldb' is not async"

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to replace Databases with SQLAlchemy 1.4 async. When I try to make the engine I get the following error:

`sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: The asyncio extension requires an async driver to be used. The loaded 'mysqldb' is not async.`

I'm making the engine like this:

```
engine = create_async_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL, future=True)
```

What is need to get mysqldb to work with SQLAlchemy async?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I figured it out, I was using this URL:

```
'mysql://someuser:passwd1234@localhost/app_db'
```

But I needed to be using something like:

```
'mysql+asyncmy://someuser:asswd1234@localhost/app_db'
```

I was missing the +asyncmy part to use the [asyncmy dialect](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/mysql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.asyncmy). I needed to install the package too:

```
pip install sqlalchemy[asyncio]
```

Comment: Currently (April 2022) [asyncmy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/mysql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.asyncmy) is preferred over [aiomysql](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/mysql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.aiomysql)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have used `pip install asyncmy` and when I run my code, it said `No module named 'asyncmy'`.

Comment: @Oscar916 if you are installing on windows, you'll need C++ buildtools to install via pip. See: https://github.com/long2ice/asyncmy?tab=readme-ov-file#installing-on-windows